# How to set concrete class properties in a generic method with parameter Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have three classes as shown below,

```
public class MyA {
    String code;
    String message;
    // and others
}
 
public class MyB {
    String code;
    String message;
    // and others
}
 
public class MyC {
    String code;
    String message;
    // and others
}
```

Somewhere in my code, I need to do the following:

```
MyA a = new MyA();
a.setCode("some code");
a.setMessage("some message");
 
MyA b = new MyB();
b.setCode("some code");
b.setMessage("some message");
 
MyA c = new MyC();
c.setCode("some code");
c.setMessage("some message");
```

There is a lot of duplicate code. I'm thinking of creating a method to take care of instantiating the class and setting the properties for me. So that I only need to do this,

```
MyA a = createAndSet(MyA.class);
MyA b = createAndSet(MyB.class);
MyA c = createAndSet(MyC.class);
```

The method would be something like this.

```
private <T> T createAndSet(Class<T> cls) {
    T t = null;
    try {
        t = cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ex)
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   
    t.setCode("some code");         // error
    t.setMessage("some message");   // error
   
    return t;
}
```

Unfortunately, the method doesn't work. Could anyone tell me the best way to handle a duplicate code situation like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don’t do any of this. Introduce an `interface` or `abstract class`.

Comment: 1) I would make all these classes extend a common class (same fields? - otherwise an interface); 2) instead of `MyA a = createAndSet(MyA.class);`, why not `MyA a = createAndSet(new MyA());` (if not passing the values in the constructor itself) - without knowing the use case, just based on some very abstract information, we cannot expect the best answer